# How can I fix Fortran Module Variables being listed as <unknown type> in Apple GDB

Tags: xcode, xcode4, gdb, fortran, ddd-debugger

Apple Xcode is unable to display any Fortran Module Variables. Module variables can be viewed by going to the Run Menu -> Show -> Global Variables

The mangling of module variables with their variable name is clear.

But when listing the value of the global variable at a breakpoint, what is shown is simply:

`<unknown type>`

I've encountered this error in XCode and DDD (also using apple's GDB). This is for module variables which are as simple as just integers - these are not derived data types.

I am on 10.6.8 using Apple's GDB `GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815` and XCode 3.2.6.

At the very least, can anyone see if Fortan module variables are accessible with later versions of XCode?

(although I see that Apple remains at GDB 6.3 even into XCode 4)

Answer (score 0):

[Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?sec=devel) offers gdb 7.4, that should support Fortran well, but probably you will have to use dd. I don't know if you can use it in Xcode. Apple will probably not deliver a newer version in the future, because of licence change to GPLv3.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well but GDB 7.4 seems to have its own problems. I'd have to make another questions for that one... The trouble is GDB 7.4 crashing out when I set more than 1 breakpoint, the error being malloc related.

Comment: And did you try to build a more recent version yourself?

Comment: Yes. The situation does not improve.